# Which are the earliest real-time text editors?

Tags: history, text, editor

A real-time text editor is a program which facilitates editing text.  In the process, the text is displayed on a screen, and the displayed text is updated after each key press.

A commonly cited example is the addition of "^R mode" to TECO which was done circa 1972.  Previous to this, TECO would only update the displayed text when the user typed Altmode (ESC) to execute entered commands.

Comment: Doesn't any kind of editing on a 3270 meet this definition?

Comment: @MichaelGraf, it's not quite what in mind, but you have a good point.

Comment: @MichaelGraf Sort of. My understanding is that much of what a 3270 did was in block mode - make changes and send/process as a block. So there is an immediate visual update but it is more like half-duplex on a TTY than a real-time update.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - Indeed. The 3270 receives a screenful of text, including mark-up (which areas can be edited), and displays it. The user then locally edits what's on the screen, and the changes are only sent back to the mainframe when the enter key is pressed. This means that the core part of what Lars defines as real time editor functionality ("text is displayed on a screen, and the displayed text is updated after each key press", + cursor movement and such) is contained in the terminal firmware, not in some editor application.

Comment: A latecomer to the party, but one which deserves an honorable mention is ["Epsilon," by Lugaru Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_(text_editor)). It delivered an Emacs-like experience on a DOS-PC, and you could _comfortably_ edit multi-megabyte files with it: The file size was limited only by the file system.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - I love Epsilon - and it's pretty long-term - but I don't think it is 1972 long-term...  But you're right - back then it delivered a fast reliable editing experience using the PC hardware of the day; a day when Emacs on the PC was just crazy talk.  (And it's still very nice BTW.)

Comment: @MichaelGraf a quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_2260 shows that the 2260 was a predecessor of the 3270 and was introduced in 1964. Page 16 of the pdf of the referenced Field Engineering Description confirms that editing was possible on the 6-line display.

Comment: The only "not real-time" editor I have used was on George 3 (ICL 1906) where I could enter a card-deck of editing commands without effect on my funny-money budget; interactive console time was increasingly expensive the more you used it.  Which is to say, "video editing" might be a better phrase for the title :-)

Comment: @MichaelGraf I had to use xedit in VM/CMS in block mode into the early ‘90s. Protocol was 3270, either hardwired or emulated. While the local line was updated, I would hardly call this real time, especially when working when white space counted. We would frequently import from Unix for the first pass, and then work on the mainframe to wrap thing up.

Comment: I had another editor in mind, called IMEDIT. It's very much like the 3270 in that the text buffer resides in an Imlac core memory, and updated text is only sent to a PDP-10 host computer when the user types XMIT PAGE. So if IMEDIT would be a real-time editor, there's no reason editing on a 3270 wouldn't be too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the following early text editors meet your criteria:

- Brian Tolliver’s TVEdit (Stanford, 1965), based on Doug Engelbart’s earlier word processor; see [On-line Text Editing: a Survey](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/356589.356591):

  > TVEDIT is one of the earliest (1965) time-sharing, CRT-based text editors [12, 22]; it displays many lines of text at electronic speed. The user thus continually views the most recent version of his text and does not have to constantly refer to a mocked-up copy. Users ordinarily create and maintain text without any hard copy, not even an initial hand-written draft.
  >
  > Because of careful user engineering, the simple TVEDIT command language is almost invisible to the experienced user. A control shift button alters the interpretation of alphanumeric keys to perform required functions. A request for these functions can be preceded by a number to repeat the command that number of times. Commands are executed as they are typed, so the user never has to press an execute command key and is seldom forced to wait for a system response.
- Fred Wright’s [E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(1970s_text_editor)) (Stanford, 1970), which helped inspire EMACS;
- TECO’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> mode, implemented by Carl Mikkelsen and then re-implemented by Richard M. Stallman, [resulting in EMACS](http://www.codeartnow.com/hacker-art-1/macsimizing-teco) (1976);
- Larry Tesler’s [Gypsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsy_%28software%29) (Xerox PARC, 1975), an early GUI-based, modeless editor.

See also [A personal history of modeless text editing and cut/copy-paste](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2212877.2212896), [Evaluation of text editors](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/800049.801770), and [Design case study: the bravo text editor](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2065327.2065342).

Comment: It's amazing how this quote celebrates features that are completely taken for granted today. See the current state of the document as you type it! Displays multiple lines of text! Create and maintain text without a hard copy! Control + an alphanumeric key gives easy access to special commands!

Comment: As someone who was saddled with only a line editor in school, I was thrilled the first time I could use an up arrow or down arrow key in a text editor...

Comment: Though `vi` holdouts seem unconvinced by the benefits of modeless editing :-)

Comment: Apropos of nothing: the thing that finally got me to give up my trusty DEC VT52 in favor of the nastier-feeling VT100 was seeing an editor showing the select range in inverse video. OK, game over, VT52 loses.

Comment: Here's a reference card to TVEDIT's commands https://exhibits.stanford.edu/feigenbaum/catalog/pf238dv0503

Comment: L Peter Deutsch says NLS was operational, with real-time editing, already in 1965.  Some sources have TVEDIT written in 1963.

Comment: @StephenKitt, I think you may need to revise your "E 1970" item.  Dan Swinehart implemented a full-screen editor called TV around 1970, written in the SAIL language.  Fred Wright came along a few years later and rewrote it in assembly language and changed the name to E.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff I may indeed, I can’t remember where I got the 1970 date. Do you have a better source than *Essential E*? ISTR dates earlier than 1970 for Dan Swinehart’s `TV` and possibly Fred Wright’s `E` as well (I can’t find anything better than https://groups.google.com/g/alt.folklore.computers/c/85IaL4BWohI now though).

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested to read about the oNLine-System developed throughout the 1960s and demonstrated by Douglas Engelbart in The Mother Of All Demos (demonstrated Dec 1968), which I believe contains real-time text editing.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree it does show real-time editing.

Comment: Technical writers, journalists, and marketing guys should be forbidden from using the words "genius", "revolutionary", "paradigm-shift", etc. until after they have watched, internalized, and *understood* this demo. Moore's Law has given us a 1000000000000000 times increase in computing power since then, so today's software *should* be able to do 1000000000000000 as much, but in reality, some of the stuff in that demo still doesn't exist today in a reasonable form.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - you missed our "patent lawyers" :-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, to understand the impact of the demo, you'd have to understand the historical context; what the previous state of the art was.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
**I think the most correct answer to this question may actually be here in this link**,   [link](https://www.cadhistory.net/03%20MIT%20CAD%20Roots%201945-1965.pdf), searching for words like "edit" "text" or "writer" .

Also, people replying to the question linked to this one claim the following 2 computers would of been capable [1st link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Baby) and [2nd link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Mark_1), although there's no evidence it was done in terms of a full alphabet and keyboard etc .

Another possibility or answer to this question ( too difficult to find information on ) is that the 'earliest real-time text editor' ( displaying on a crt ) may in no way have been connected to a computer, it may have simply been some sort of simple electromechanical system containing a video-memory somehow using something like Charactrons ( Charactron, Typotron, Monoscope, and the very earliest the Monotron ) with the video memory just storing coordinates linked to a specific character ), all done without a computer, but using a keyboard, or some other similar method but not using things like Charactrons but using some other type of video memory.

Also not forgetting the Motograph patented in 1923 [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker), the rolling text adverts up on buildings made of light-bulbs, individual letters were placed in frames on a conveyor belt which touched electrical contacts .
**_________________________**

For the PDP-1, the first machine was actually delivered in 1959, there seems to have been a crt ( publicised with the tv type crt screen in 1959 ), which displayed text.

I used to have a much higher quality photo of the text on the crt, where you could magnify it and see the font, but now I can only find the image below, and also the image without the text.

The images shown below, are from the following sites -
  - [information and photos](https://history-computer.com/ModernComputer/Electronic/PDP-1.html)
  - [photo](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/ancient-comp/pdp1_2.jpg)

I have no further information about the text on the PDP-1 crt, although maybe it's related to the above mentioned TVEDIT .
**_________________________**

You may already know about the following question, not sure if it's a duplicate, which includes a question and information ( in the comments ) about some radar screens which displayed text, and a machine in the late 1940's  - [First computer to have interactive text on a CRT?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11550/first-computer-to-have-interactive-text-on-a-crt)
**_________________________**

The Whirlwind computer in 1949
    Quote from this website [webpage](http://christoph-knoth.com/shared/computed_type_-_christoph_knoth.pdf)  "Whirlwind went operational in 1949. It
was the first digital computer capable of displaying real time text and graphics on a
video terminal, which was an oscilloscope screen."

Searching for keywords like "whirlwind" "crt"   "text" "editor"gets results like this [link](https://books.google.es/books?id=K4YlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%22whirlwind%22%20%22crt%22%20%20%20%22text%22%20%22editor%22&source=bl&ots=FvXzzIzD_O&sig=ACfU3U2IbFt7x-plGiaZWkR2l9i2mYB_jQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd94e2oOTpAhXHDWMBHR6wA4EQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22whirlwind%22%20%22crt%22%20%20%20%22text%22%20%22editor%22&f=false)

**_________________________**

Also -
 - the small desktop sized, crt screen calculator, Friden EC-130 of 1963, which was then copied by other companies .
 - the  IBM 2260 of 1964 ( [information and photo](http://www.righto.com/2019/11/ibm-sonic-delay-lines-and-history-of.html) , [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_2260) )

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  These are interesting, but it's unclear whether there's a text editor program involved displaying the text.

Comment: Were those letters drawn as a raster, or as vectors, or by steering the beam through letter-shaped holes in a metal plate before steering the letter-shaped beam to the desired location on the CRT surface?

Comment: I couldn't find if the text was raster or vector, however it seems maybe the reason why you hardly ever see the PDP-1 with this tv type of crt is that it may have been   "The PDP-1A prototype as depicted in Datamation" ( a quote from https://www.masswerk.at/rc2016/10/01.html ). Re your comment "steering the beam through letter-shaped holes in a metal plate before steering the letter-shaped beam to the desired location on the CRT surface",  many months ago I found a patent ( or patents ) for that, however it was for tv-station-broadcasting not for computers I think .

Comment: I'm thinking your comment on the duplicate-? question regarding radars "some RADAR displays had two sets of deflection controls, so that the beam would first pass through a selectable aperture within a plate and then from there be aimed at the proper position on the screen" must have been very difficult for a machine/computer to assign text-characters to individual radar-detections especially when they got too close to each other, they would get objects/detections on radar mixed up, note,  transparencies ( using ink that would glow when it was hit by the electron-beam ) also existed

Comment: Systems using metal stencils ( or other methods ) inside the crt to create text on the the crt screen, were the Charactron, Typotron, Monoscope, and the very earliest the Monotron, from the book   https://books.google.es/books?id=KTA6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22crt%22+%22characters%22+++%22control+grid%22+++%22television%22&source=bl&ots=GtxotmxIdf&sig=ACfU3U2dv4YWMFDJ7M_ZXmV1BoYA8jgjLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWy-3T6ebpAhUhyoUKHb6WBW8Q6AEwF3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22crt%22%20%22characters%22%20%20%20%22control%20grid%22%20%20%20%22television%22&f=false

Comment: @supercat, there was a character generator for the Type 30 CRT display.  I'm not sure how it works, but I believe it was point plotting like the rest of the Type 30.  Certainly the later Type 340 does it that way.

Comment: @mnml: I wonder if one could use a device that was like a TV camera, but with electrostatic deflection, and with a pattern screened on the phosphor, as a sort of character-generator ROM?  I remember in the late 1970s noticing that airport flight displays were shown on ordinary raster screens, but the white-on-black lettering looked "analog", but updated instantaneously (so I don't think the boards were simply a camera pointed at a mechanical display).  A camera with an electrostatic deflection that combined a DAC-generated character-select signal with analog sawtooth waves...

Comment: ...might yield a high-quality analog display with clearer letter shapes than later digital character generators, but perhaps be more expensive to operate and maintain (I imagine calibration might be tricky), thus justifying replacement.

Comment: @mnml: As for the Charactertron, that sounds like precisely what I was thinking of; I remain curious whether any are still operational.

Comment: For your idea, I think you know about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_tube. The Charactron, Typotron, Monoscope, and the very earliest the Monotron,  did not all use identical methods, some did use 'electrostatic deflection' while others just used the electrons that got through the metal-stencil, and some different versions also seemed to work differently ?. The Charactron ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charactron ) was also used as memory, and each Charactron contained 64 or 116 characters .

Comment: I also saw the train and flight displays you refer to in that time frame, HOWEVER, I more specifically remember clocks on crts !, and even earlier on earlier made movies and tv programs, image here https://www.shorpy.com/node/14644, sure, some must have been simply cameras aimed at a mechanical-display, but I clearly remember noticing that there were some that in just no way looked like they were from a camera, even if they used extra special contrast light adjustment and special paint or phosphor coating so the camera would not transmit any give away details .

Comment: Can't remember clearly, I recently read that maybe there was one of the things like the Charactron or others that used plates to form individual parts of a character like digital led, not sure though ?. If any of those crt displays were not just cameras aimed at mechanical displays, then surely those crts were either hooked up to some sort of simple elctromechanical-system containing a video-memory all without needing any computer, or,  the crt contained something like a Charactron, keeping in mind I more specifically remember clocks on crts !

Comment: So, relevant to this question, another possibility or answer to this question is that the 'earliest real-time text editor' ( displaying on a crt ) 
may in no way have been connected to a computer, it may have simply been some sort of simple electromechanical-system containing a video-memory all without needing any computer, or somehow using something like Charactrons ( video memory just storing coordinates linked to a specific character ), all done without a computer, but using a keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

If by program you go with the more generic definition that would be a procedure by which something is done, I would have to say that it was probably a stick and clay tablet.  It was definitely more forgiving to corrections than the hammer and chisel on stone 'program' and tended to be more portable than the stick and sand 'program' that came before it. :)

One could consider punch cards to be a real time text editor.

Comment: If you redefine program to mean procedure and then redefine screen to mean a piece of card and then redefine text to mean holes then this does indeed work. Completely changing the meaning of all the key words in a question does make most of them easier to answer.

Comment: Hey, don't knock those ol' punch cards... It was easy to move lines of text around in your "document"... And they usually had the text for the codes printed on the top of the card also...